# Can scrapy step through a website by following "next" button

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Can scrapy save a web page, follow the next button and save the next web page etc.,  in a series of search results? It always needs to follow the "next" button and nothing else.

This is the url (obfuscated) that links to the next page:

erthdata.---.com/full_record.do?product=UA&search_mode=GeneralSearch&qid=21&SID=d89sduisd&excludeEventConfig=ExcludeIfFromFullRecPage&page=1&doc=4&cacheurlFromRightClick=no

Thanks

John

Comment: You need to be more specific: show the relevant parts of an html page at least. At most provide a link to the web-site you are crawling. Also, have you personally tried anything? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar to this:

```
def parse(self, response):

    saveWebpage()

    if checkHasNextButton():

        yield Request(
            url=getNextUrl(),
            callback=self.parse
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

It sure can, there is multiple way:

1. Add SgmlLinkextractor to follow that next link.
2. Or make Request in your function, like yield(Request(url))

In your case url = erthdata.---.com/full_record.do?product=UA&search_mode=GeneralSearch&qid=21&SID=d89sduisd&excludeEventConfig=ExcludeIfFromFullRecPage&page=1&doc=4&cacheurlFromRightClick=no